# Can I $watch a property once and then forget about it?

Tags: alpine.js

My component needs to act upon a property change *once*, during initialization. Subsequent changes to the property do not require any action.

I've currently solved this with a workaround like the one below. Is there a better way to `$watch` something once?

```js
const Component = () => ({
  property: ""
  hasInitialized: false,
  init() {
    this.$watch("property", (value, oldValue) => {
      if (!this.hasInitialized) {
        // Go do something
        this.hasInitialized = true;
      }
    });
  }
});

export default Component;
```

Comment: Does it trigger an event by change? You can handle listeners only once, see example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#example_of_options_usage)

Comment: No event there unfortunately. This question is specific to AlpineJS.

Comment: Then I have no clue either. Can't find any other threads about this either. Quite silly that there's no simple way to just stop watching a property.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there's no public/documented API to do that.

However based on the `$watch` implementations in Alpine v2 and v3, I think it's possible to do in v2 but not v3

#### v2

The component instance is under `el.__x`, watchers are `el.__x.watchers[propertyName]` so we can probably delete the watcher for the property name.

```html
<script>
function Component() {
  return {
    property: "Hello Alpine",
    init() {
      this.$watch('property', () => {
        console.log('$watch("property") running');
        delete this.$el.__x.watchers.property;
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
<div x-data="Component()" x-init="init">
  <input x-model="property" />
  <div>Output: <span x-text="property"></span></div>
</div>
```

#### v3

Here's the `$watch` implementation: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/3b518739ed975b135249f16dccac135c0add9add/packages/alpinejs/src/magics/%24watch.js

To delete the effect we need a reference for it, this is what happens here https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/3b518739ed975b135249f16dccac135c0add9add/packages/alpinejs/src/magics/%24watch.js#L33. But we don't have a reference to the right `watch` effect.

Comment: Clear, thanks for this explanation. I'll add a feature request.